Solve the power equation $\;2\!\cdot\!3^{x^2}=6^x$

Solve the power equation $\;2\!\cdot\!3^{x^2}=6^x.$


$$2 \cdot 3^{x^{2}} = 6^x $$
$$log_3(9) \cdot log_3(3^{x^{2}}) = log_3(6^x)  $$
$$2x^2 - xlog_3(6) = 0  $$
$$x(2x - log_3(6)) = 0$$
$$x = 0$$ or $$x = \frac{log_3(6)}{2}$$
What do I do wrong? Task from school math about logarithm
I has the first equation on the top of picture and try to logarithm them for different base. First is 3, second is 2 and third is 6 and everywhere get solution x = 0 but it is not a solution of first equation. Where I lost some limitations for the range of acceptable values or something else? I mean, I solve the second equation the same way and get right solutions I think...

What do I do wrong?
Is the easy way to check yourself solution with logarithm? Put the solution into equation when it comes logarithm is hard
Where I lost some limitations?


Firefly, you should write $$\log_3\left(2\cdot3^{x^2}\right)=\log_36^x$$ $$\log_32+\log_33^{x^2}=\log_36^x$$instead of $$\color{red}{\log_39,\cdot}\log_33^{x^2}=\log_36^x.$$

Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

You can solve a quadratic too: $x^2\ln(3)-x\ln(6)+\ln(2)=0\iff (x-1)(\ln(3)x-\ln(2))=0$

@Angelo Could you write how it works? I think we make logarithm of each arguments but right is make logarithm of all part of equality

You have to use $log(a\cdot b)=log(a)+log(b)$ and you have to tell us how you come up with log(9)

@trula Could you write how it works? I think we make logarithm of each arguments but right is make logarithm of all part of equality. It mistake can make possible log(9)

Put $2 = 3^a$ then $$2.3^{x^2} = 6^x 
\\ \iff 3^{a+x^2} = 3^x\cdot2^x
\\ \iff 3^{a+x^2} = 3^x\cdot 3^{ax}
\\ \iff x^2 - (a+1)x + a = 0
\\ \iff (x-1)(x-a) = 0
\\ \iff x =1,a$$
